# Get absolute path of application from nested import

Tags: python, path

My application structure looks as followed:

```
main.py
modules
 -- module.py
```

*main.py* imports *module.py*.

In *module.py* I want to fetch the absolute file path of *main.py*. What is the best and most efficient way to do this?

Comment: might be easier for `main` to tell it! otherwise you could keep getting the parent of `__file__` until you find `main.py`

Comment: That's indeed easier, but that doesn't work with my structure :/ And yes, I've considered that option but it isn't very elegant in my opinion. I'm looking for a simple function to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If its always the same structure you can do:

```
from pathlib import Path

main_script = Path(__file__).parent.parent / "main.py"
```

If it can be any level deep, you can iteratively go up parent folders until you find it

```
search_dir = Path(__file__).parent

while not (search_dir / "main.py").exists():
    search_dir = search_dir.parent

main_script = search_dir / "main.py"
```

If it could be something more complicated, you will need to do some sort of recursive search

Comment: beware: this will get stuck if it never finds! I'd add another check to break on `/`